# Wrong math result with calling C extension in Python

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I am calling the `pow()` function of C's math library. My installation is Python3.5 on Windows 10 but I tried the same program in Python2.7 with same result. The return from the function is not as expected. Not sure what's happening. The code is given below. The result I get is 1.0.

```
from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.msvcrt
libc.pow.argtypes = [c_double, c_int]
libc.pow.restype = c_double
libc.pow(2.3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your types, I'm pretty sure the prototype for pow is

> double pow(double a, double b);

So changes this line

> libc.pow.argtypes = [c_double, c_int]

To

> libc.pow.argtypes = [c_double, c_double]

Whenever you call c functions from python always make sure the types you are inputting from python are correct, don't rely on casting like you would in c/c++

Comment: That's correct. Looks like an interface bug. It should catch this as wrong argument type instead of returning wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

There is a type mismatch. Use c_double for power as well.
Like this. It should work.

libc.pow.argtypes = [c_double, c_double]

Comment: IIRC, your "also" addendum is superfluous.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

pow in C libray takes double, double as input arguments. That's why.

```
from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.msvcrt
libc.pow.argtypes = [c_double, c_double]
libc.pow.restype = c_double
libc.pow(2.3, 2.0)
```